# Select em Entity Framework não está funcionando

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Estou realizando uma consulta utilizando LINQ, consulta bem simples estou utilizando o seguinte método.

```
public void verificaAcesso( string usuario, string senha)
{
    using (DbBancoContext banco = new DbBancoContext())
    {
        var resultadoConsulta = from u in banco.USUARIOS_PROCESSO
                                where
                                   u.USUARIO == usuario
                                   && u.SENHA == senha
                                   && u.DT_CANCELAMENTO != null
                                select u.ID_USUARIO;
    }
}
```

Só que não estou tendo retorno algum mas quando verifico o conteúdo da variável `resultadoConsulta` exibe o seguinte conteúdo.

```
{SELECT [Extent1].[ID_USUARIO] AS [ID_USUARIO]
 FROM [dbo].[USUARIOS_PROCESSO] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE ([Extent1].[USUARIO] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[SENHA] = @p__linq__1) AND ([Extent1].[DT_CANCELAMENTO] IS NOT NULL)}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Ola. A consulta nao foi ainda efectuada, so sera efectuada quando utilizar o resultado. Para trazer logo o resultado pode adicionar `.ToList()` no final da query.

Comment: @Omni Eu dei um +1 no seu comentário mas seria bacana responder a pergunta. Apenas pelo seu comentário, ninguém poderia me condenar por tentar fazer `...select u.ID_USUARIO.ToList();` na última linha.

Comment: @Caffé estava a sair do trabalho e nao deu, mas ainda bem que respondeu =) upvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione uma linha:

`var idsUsuarios = resultadoConsulta.ToList();` O resultado estará em `idsUsuarios`.

Ou envolva sua query por parêntesis, adicionando o nela uma chamada para `ToList`:

```
    var resultadoConsulta = (from u in banco.USUARIOS_PROCESSO
                            where
                               u.USUARIO == usuario
                               && u.SENHA == senha
                               && u.DT_CANCELAMENTO != null
                            select u.ID_USUARIO).ToList();
```

e daí sim o resultado estará em `resultadoConsulta`.

O que seu código faz até agora é apenas criar a query e não executá-la.

Comment: Sua ajuda foi boa mas tem um pequeno problema no meu caso quando verifico o valor do resultado ele me da um count = 0 será que não seria erro na minha connectionstring

Comment: @Rabelos O único erro que imagino na `connectionstring` é ela estar apontando para a base errada, de outro modo você teria uma exceção e não uma quantidade inesperada de registros. Parece que simplesmente não há registros que satisfaçam o filtro. Verifique: letras maiúsculas e minúsculas no nome do usuário (o banco pode estar case sensitive), se a senha está criptografada no banco e não criptografada na consulta, se os usuários cujos Ids você pretendia retornar realmente foram cancelados (DT_CANCELAMENTO != null).

Comment: @Rabelos Se fosse pra apostar, eu diria que o teu filtro de data de cancelamento está equivocado. Da maneira como está, você só retorna o ID dos usuários que "foram cancelados" (campo `DT_CANCELAMENTO != null`), se é que esta é a sua linguagem de negócio. Será que não deveria ser `&& u.DT_CANCELAMENTO == null`?

Comment: Reparei nisso meu caro @Caffé distraído pela raiva do não entendimento uahuauahau. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.